# Probability of Y, where $Y=X^2$ and $X \sim U[-1, 1]$

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions, density-function, change-of-variable

I'm trying to prove that if $X \sim U[-1, 1]$ and $Y = X^2$ then $p_Y(y)=\frac{1}{2} y^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, using the **change of variables** theorem.

The theorem states one can show that $p_Y(y) = \frac{dx}{dy} p_X(x)$.

Given the problem above, I find that $p_X(x) = \frac{1}{b-a} = \frac{1}{2}$. And that $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{d}{dy}\sqrt{y} = \frac{1}{2}y^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

Therefore,
$$ p_Y(y) = \frac{dx}{dy}p_X(x) = \frac{1}{4}y^{-\frac{1}{2}} $$

But I know that it's not true, since $p_Y(y) = \frac{1}{2}y^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. So
where is the problem?

Comment: You shouldn't write $p_y(y)$ when you mean $p_Y(y),$ nor $p_x(x)$ when you mean $p_X(x).$ Without distinguishing between $x$ and $X$ and between $y$ and $Y,$ you can't even understand something like $\Pr(X\le x). \qquad$

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
F_Y(y) = P( Y \le y) = P(X^2 \le y) = P( - \sqrt{y} \le X \le \sqrt{y}) = \frac{\sqrt y + 1}{2} - \frac{-\sqrt y + 1}{2} = \sqrt y,
\end{align}
thus
$$
f_Y(y) = \frac{\partial }{\partial y}F_Y(y) = \frac{1}{2}y^ {-1/2}
$$
Namely, your formula works only for one-to-one functions. In this case, using the transformation formula is equivalent to considering only the positive side, i.e.,
$
P(X\le \sqrt y)
$, that gives you the $1/4$ instead of $1/2$ when you deriving the density function.

Answer (score 1):

The change of variables only works where $f$ is injective - you have $+x$ and $-x$ counting twice in $X$’s distribution and once in $Y$. You can split $X$ into $[-1,0]$ and $[0,1]$ calculate the distribution of Y from each (which you’ve done and are the same), and add giving double your answer.

Comment: I want to clarify when you said I can split $X$ into $[-1,0]$ and $[0,1]$ and calculate distribution of Y from each. This does not mean calculating probability from $X \sim U[-1, 0]$ , right? Because I find that $P(X \le \sqrt{y}) = \sqrt{y} + 1$ and therefore $p_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy} \sqrt{y} + 1 = \frac{1}{2} y^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ instead of my answer above.

Comment: In the example above I mean the $X \sim U[0, 1]$ so that we can use $P(X \le \sqrt{y})$ and not $P(\sqrt{y} \le X)$

Comment: No, you’re just only including contributions from the positive x root right now. You need to sum over all $x$ see the “Scalar to Scalar” subsection of “Function of random variables...” in

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Multiple_variables